# How do I add SolrInputDocument or XML as value into camel-solr xml route?

Tags: apache-camel

```
<route>
    <from uri="direct:insert"/>
    <setHeader headerName="SolrOperation">
        <constant>INSERT</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <setHeader headerName="SolrField.id">
        <simple>${body}</simple>
    </setHeader>
    <to uri="solr://localhost:8983/solr"/>
</route>
```

This is sample code to set ${body} to a 'id' field, but since it supports message body as SolrInputDocument or equivalent XML, how am I suppose to do that in above XML route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have the SolrInputDocument, then just pass it as the body of a message to the route and make sure the OPERATION header is set appropriately...

```
//example producer code
SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
doc.addField("id", "MA147LL/A", 1.0f);
template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:start", doc, SolrConstants.OPERATION, SolrConstants.OPERATION_INSERT);

//simplified route that just expects the message body and OPERATION header are setup appropriately
<from uri="direct:insert"/>
<to uri="solr://localhost:8983/solr"/>
```

see the unit tests for more information...

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-solr/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/solr/SolrUpdateTest.java

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but can I set that up in plain XML, like above? Or I have to that in JAVA code?

Comment: the route can be in XML or Java...its the same either way